# Add a link to an image in a css style sheet

Tags: css, hyperlink, stylesheet

I am looking to add a link to an image in a CSS style sheet so it will navigate to the link when the image is pressed.

The code for the image itself is:

```
 #logo{
    background-image: url(images/logo.png);
    width: 981px;
    height: 180px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

What is the code to add to allow it to navigate to a hyperlink?  For example:  If I wanted it to navigate to http://home.com

Comment: check at my edit please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not do that...

via css the `URL` you put on the `background-image` is just for the image.

Via `HTML` you have to add the `href` for your hyperlink in this way:

```
<a href="http://home.com" id="logo">Your logo</a>
```

With `text-indent` and some other `css` you can adjust your a element to show just the image and clicking on it you will go to your link.

---

EDIT:

I'm here again to show you and explain why my solution is much better:

```
<a href="http://home.com" id="logo">Your logo name</a>
```

This block of `HTML` is **SEO friendly** because you have some text inside your link!

How to style it with css:

```
#logo {
  background-image: url(images/logo.png);
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 981px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

Then if you don't care about **SEO** good to choose the other answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes suggested but the text appears and the hyperlink doesn't appear to be linked to the image.  Teh site with changes is at http://www.towels.co.za, not my site, but one i am trying to fix for a friend and trying to find my way around his code

Comment: Ok, found the error- he hadn't included the style sheet in the header...  I had considered the SEO issues, but since I was struggling with CSS (mainly since the last time I wrote HTML code was close to a decade ago...) I put it in the background just wanting to get the site working as needed

Answer (score 2):

You don't add links to style sheets.  They are for describing the style of the page.  You would change your mark-up or add JavaScript to navigate when the image is clicked.

Based only on your style you would have:

```
<a href="home.com" id="logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
<a href="http://home.com"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" id="logo"></a>
```

in HTML

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this old listing pondering this same question. My band-aid for this same question was to make my header text into a link. I then changed the color and removed text decoration with CSS. Now to make the entire header picture a link, I expanded the padding of the anchor tag until it reached close to the edge of the header image.... This worked to my satisfaction, and I figured i would share.