# How to hyperlink an image through CSS?

Tags: php, css

This is the `CSS` that I am using to display the logo of my site. And I need to make it into a hyperlink that that I can direct the User to the homepage, but I am not able to accomplish.

```
.logo{
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    border: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 105px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0F3C86;
    background-image: url("../Images/logo1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is my approach correct? Is there any alternative to get the result I want? I am using `PHP` to implement my site.

Comment: Why use CSS to place a hyperlink? CSS is only used to style a page.

Could you try this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730484/add-a-link-to-an-image-in-a-css-style-sheet

Comment: html: <a href="#" class="logo"></a>, css: your css, and add display: block;
good luck! :)